How can $p_n\leq 2^{2^{n-1}}$ if gaps between prime numbers can be arbitrarily large?
I just started learning elementary number theory, and I am working through an introductory number theory textbook, where I only completed 2 chapters - about the division algorithm, divisibility properties. However, two of the problems from chapter 3 (introduction to prime numbers) made me really confused.
The first problem asked:

Prove that within the natural number line there are arbitrary long gaps, not containing prime numbers.

The second problem asked:

Prove that $$p_n\leq2^{2^{n-1}}$$
where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime number.

I did not yet manage to prove either of them, but what confuses me about these problems is that they seemingly contradict each other in my eyes.
I mean, assuming that there are arbitrary long gaps between prime numbers, then hypothetically I could find consecutive prime numbers $p_k,p_{k-1}$ such that the gap between them is $2^{2^{k-1}}$ numbers (excluding $p_k,p_{k-1}$), meaning that $$p_k=p_{k-1}+2^{2^{k-1}}+1>2^{2^{k-1}}$$
which contradicts what the second problem asked me to prove.
Can somebody help me wrap my head around how these two statements can be true at the same time? And, if possible, please avoid giving me answers to the aforementioned textbook problems; I want to try to prove them on my own.
Thank you in advance!

you are using the same $k$ to mean two different things

A hint for the fist question : Start with $n!$ and look how far you can be sure to have only composite numbers.

@MatthewTowers I'm not sure I follow, can you please elaborate on that?

Your title question: because the gaps for $2^{2^{n-1}}$ also get arbitrarily large. The first values are $2,4,16,256,65563$ and the gaps are growing fast!

arbitrarily large gaps implies that for any $k$, there's some pair of consecutive primes differing by at least $2^{2^k}$. But there's no reason it should be $p_k$ and $p_{k+1}$ that differ by at least that amount.

@DietrichBurde But what if there is a gap between prime numbers (since they can of arbitrary length) that makes some $p_n$ jump over $2^{2^{n-1}}$? Or is it impossible?

You need to take the $n$-th prime, or the $n$-th term of a sequence. So the gaps of primes $2,3,5,7,11,$ are very small compared to the gaps of $2,4,16,256,65563$. You cannot compare gaps at different "places". Of course the gap from $2$ to $4$ is small, and the prime gap $7,11$ is already bigger. But here we look at different places.

May be consider a simpler example. Although $n^2\le 2^n$ for $n\ge 4$, the sequence $n^2$ has arbitrarily large gaps. The first sequence starts with $16,25,36,49,\ldots$, and the second one is $16,32,64,128,256,\ldots$.

@DietrichBurde I think I misunderstand the word "arbitrary". I see "arbitrary" in the same way as "random", so it makes me think that gaps between prime numbers can come randomly and a sequence of gaps of, for example, $\dots 1,4,2$ somewhere in $p_n$ can be abruptly followed by an absurd gap of $65432425\dots 1$ that makes $p_n$ overleap the corresponding $n$-th term in the sequence $2^{2^{n-1}}$. Maybe this is where I am thinking wrong and this is not possible?

Consider an easy to example to understand the words. Take the sequence of square numbers $1,4,9,16,25,36,\ldots$. We say that it has arbitrarily large gaps, if for every $c>1$ there exists an $n$ with $(n+1)^2-n^2>c$.

Consider Graham's number , a number so huge that its magnitude cannot be comprehended , beyond what most people would consider to be virtually infinite (of course not really because it is still a finite number !) We know that there are CONSECUTIVE primes having a difference of more than Graham's number. In short , there is no upper bound for the magnitude of a prime gap , this is what it is meant with "arbitary large".

Your first statement says, that if you choose any $N \in \mathbb{N}$, then there is a pair of consequtive primes, that differ by at least $N$. This however does not tell you anything about for which primes does it happen. So you know nothing about the indices of those primes. Thus you can't say, that you can pick $p_{k-1}, p_k$ with gap $2^{2^{k-1}}$, since if you decide to set $N = 2^{2^{k-1}}$, then this gap will be achieved, but by some primes with indices larger than $k$.

Aaaah, I see now. Thank you so much for clarifying!

The upper bound of $2^{2^{n-1}}$ can be shown by considering the sequence of Fermat numbers, $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$. One can rewrite it as $a(n)=(2^{2^n}-1)+2$.
A number whose base-$b$ expansion is a series of $n$ $1$s is writable as $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(b^i\right)=\frac{b^n-1}{b-1}$. If $n$ is divisible by $d$, one can group this sum into length-$d$ subsections,
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\frac nd-1}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{d-1}\left(b^j\right)*b^{d*i}\right)=\sum_{j=0}^{d-1}\left(b^j\right)*\sum_{i=0}^{\frac nd-1}\left(b^{d*i}\right)=\frac{b^d-1}{b-1}*\frac{b^n-1}{b^d-1}$$
By inductively applying this, we get $\frac{b^{2^n}-1}{b-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{2^n-1}(b^i)=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(b^{2^i}+1)$. With $b=2$, this gives $F_n=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(F_i)+2$. Since all Fermat numbers are odd, this means no Fermat number shares any factors with any other, so each one must account for at least one prime $\le$ itself. As such, since the prime function usually starts with $p(1)=2$ and the Fermat primes wiith $F_0=2^{2^0}+1=3$, one has $p(2)=F_0$, and in general $p(n)\le F_{n-2}=2^{2^{n-2}}+1$.
Sylvester's sequence is an infinite sequence of coprime elements beginning at $a(0)=2$, where each is the product of all preceding it, plus $1$ instead of $2$, which has a base of double-exponentiation of only $1.26408473...$ (A076393), but number theory has obtained much better bounds.
